# If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution and $a_n \to 0$ then $a_nX_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution. (Counterexample?)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I am enjoying studying probability theory a lot but sometimes the proofs can be a bit too fiddly for me.  Here is the question I am working on now:

If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution and $a_n \to 0$ then $a_nX_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution where $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers.

**What is says in the solutions**

I basically need to show that $F_{a_nX_n}(x) = \mathbb{P}[a_nX_n \leq x] \to \mathbb{1}_{x\geq0}
(x)$

Then split this into where $x>0$ first. And fix some $\epsilon$ and lots of other stuff.

**The way I wanted to do it**

I come from a more measure theory \pure mathsy background so wanted to try and do something like this:

Take any continious bounded function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then I want to show that $\mathbb{E}[f(a_nX_n)] = \int f(a_nX_n) d\mathbb{P} \to \mathbb{E}[f(0)] = f(0)$

I want to utilise the dominated convergence theorem as $f $ is bounded but I don't know how to show that $a_nX_n \to  0$ almost everywhere / surely. Because lets say there are some $\omega$  such that $X_n(\omega) = \infty$ then I'm sure that $a_nX_n(\omega) = \infty$ for all $n$

Does the fact that $X_n \to X$ in distribution mean that this doesn't happen?

I remember reading somewhere we must only consider continuity points when dealing with convergence in distribution so does this let me throw out the infinite values?

**Counter example?**

Having now typed this all out and thought about it some more I think the following is a counter example.

Let $X_n$ be the random variable that takes value $\frac{1}{n}$ with probability half and "value" $\infty$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then  for $ x > 0 $ $ \mathbb{P}[X_n \leq x] \to \frac{1}{2}$ and for $ x \leq 0 $ $ \mathbb{P}[X_n \leq x] = 0$ always.

Hence $X_n \to X$ in distribution where $X$ takes value $0$ or $\infty$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

However $a_nX_n \to X$ in distribution not $0$

**Apologies**

Having read back at all of this I reckon I have violated about 40 rules of maths and probability.  And all my multiplying by $\infty$ is very illegal but could someone give little pointers as to where I am making my mistakes. I dont want full answers (yet!) I want to do it myself.

Feel free to just edit the question with pointers on my mistakes :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Slutsky's theorem ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I do indeed but this module is more focused on proofs from the ground up, I met Slutskys in mathematical stats and dont think it will be valid here!

Comment: There os a result Skorokhod and Dudley that shows that there is a probability space and sequences $X'_n$ such that $X_n=X'_n$ and $X=X'$ in distribution and such that $X'_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}X'$ pointwise. So, in distribution $a_nX_n=a_nX'_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and so $a_nX_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution. The book of O. Kallenberg contains a good explanation of these kinds of things.

Comment: @BearCakes100 For the record, by Slutsky's theorem $(X_n,a_n)\xrightarrow{d} (X,0)$ and by the continuous mapping theorem $f(X_n,a_n)\xrightarrow{d} f(X,0)$ where $f:(x,y)\mapsto xy$, yielding $a_nX_n \xrightarrow{d}  0$.

Comment: A more pedestrian way is to look at characteristic $\phi_n$ and $\phi$ functions of $X_n$ and $X$ respectively,  and used the fact that converges of $\phi_n$ to $\phi$ is uniform in compact sets.

Comment: @OliverDiaz the thing on characteristics has seems very helpful!! I reckon it would be slightly easier with moment generators instead. Would this yield the same result?

Comment: @BearCakes100:The issue with moment generating functions is that $e^{sX_n}$ may not be integrable. But yea, the idea would be the same. For a more direct approach (from the definition of weak convergence) take a look at John Dawkins's answer. There are a few details to fill ion but it is rather complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be bounded (say $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x$) and continuous. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Because $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$, you can choose $N$ so large that $\sup_n P(|X_n|>N)<\epsilon$. Because $f$ is continuous, you can choose $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ if $|x|<\delta$. Finally, because $\lim_na_n =0$, there is $n_0$ such that if $n>n_0$ then $|a_n|N<\delta$. You now have, for $n>n_0$,
$$
\eqalign{
|E[f(a_nX_n)]-f(0)|
&\le E[|f(a_nX_n)-f(0)|; |X_n|\le N]+2M P[|X_n|>N]\cr
&\le \epsilon+2M\epsilon\cr
} 
$$
Because $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this proves that $\lim_n E[f(a_nX_n)]=f(0)$.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for contributing! Could you please explain a little about the statement " Because →, you can choose  so large that sup(||>)<."  As you seen in my little "counter-example" at the botton, if X_n takes infinite values this need not be the case" as for all N $P(X_n > N) = \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: Effectively I am looking at cases where $X_n$ can take values infinity

Comment: @Bearcakes100 Unless otherwise stated, a random variable is a measurable function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, so in particular, $X_n$ cannot take the non-real value $\infty$.  (This is even implied in your own work when you write $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @BearCakes: The statement involving $N$ is a reflection of the *tightness* of the sequence $(X_n)$, a consequence of its convergence in distribution. Because $P(X\in\Bbb R)=1$, you can choose $N$ so that $P(|X|>N)<\epsilon/2$. Increasing $N$ slightly if necessary, you can arrange that both $N$ and $-N$ are continuity points of the cdf of $X$. Then $\lim_n P(|X_n|>N)=P(|X|>N)$, so there exists $n_0$ such that if $n>n_0$ then
$$
|P(|X_n|>N)-P(|X|>N)|<\epsilon/2,
$$
in which case $P(|X_n|>N)<\epsilon$.